# Existence of Analytic function on unit disk $f(1/2)=3/4$ and $f'(1/2)=2/3$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Does there exist an analytic function ? $$f:A \rightarrow A$$
Such that $$f\Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big)=\frac{3}{4}$$
And $$f'\Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big)=\frac{2}{3}$$
Where $ A=\{z : |z| <1\}$.

I think that the answer is No since$|f(1/2)|=3/4$ and $3/4 >1/2$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma#Schwarz.E2.80.93Pick_theorem

Comment: @CountIblis I'll define $g(z)=f(z+\frac{1}{2}) - \frac{3}{4}$ So that $g(0)=0$ to use Schwarz lemma . but How can I use Schwarz lemma here to answer my question ?

Comment: Have you seen the Schwarz–Pick theorem in terms of $f(z)$ and its derivative in the link I gave? You can use that one, the proof is also given in the link.

Answer (score 0):

Define $\varphi(z) = \frac{\frac{3}{4} - z}{1 - \frac{3}{4}z}$, $\psi(z) = \frac{\frac{1}{2} - z}{1 - \frac{1}{2}z}$. Then see that $\varphi \circ f \circ \psi^{-1}(0) = 0$, and $\varphi \circ f \circ \psi^{-1}: \mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$. Now using Schwarz lemma, we have:

$|\varphi \circ f \circ \psi^{-1}(z)| \leq |z| \implies |\frac{\frac{3}{4} - f(\psi^{-1}(z))}{|z||(1- \frac{3}{4} f(\psi^{-1}(z))|}| \leq 1$
See Since $\psi \circ \psi  = id$, hence $\psi^{-1} = \psi$. Now let $z \rightarrow 0$ and we have:

$\lim_{z \rightarrow 0}|\frac{\frac{3}{4} - f(\psi(z))}{|z|}|\leq |(1- \frac{3}{4} f(\psi(z))| \implies \psi'(0) . f'(\frac{1}{2}) \leq 1 - \frac{3}{4} f(\frac{1}{2}) \implies \frac{3}{4}. \frac{2}{3} \leq 1 - \frac{3}{4}. \frac{3}{4} \implies \frac{1}{2} \leq \frac{7}{16}$

This is contradiction. So, there exists no such function.